# Which computer scientists have received the Turing Award specifically for their contributions to Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: history, ai-field, turing-award

Many people have heard of Hinton, Bengio, and LeCun in recent years, given the popularity of deep learning and neural networks, and their contributions to this subfield of Artificial Intelligence. For their contributions, [they have conjointly received the Turing Award in 2019](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11623/2444) (although, in my view, a few other people could also have received this award for the same reasons).

In addition to them, which computer scientists have received the Turing Award specifically for their contributions to Artificial Intelligence?

For each of them, please, describe the specific reason why they were awarded and/or provide the links to the official site that announces this or the [Turing lecture](https://amturing.acm.org/lectures.cfm).

Why am I asking this question? Alan Turing is considered one of the fathers, if not the father, of Artificial Intelligence and Computer Science. In particular, in addition to the development of Turing machines, which are widely studied in Theoretical Computer Science and Theory of Computation, he's also published the famous paper [Computing Machinery and Intelligence](https://academic.oup.com/mind/article/LIX/236/433/986238) in 1950, where he proposed what was later called the Turing test, and asked one of the most fundamental questions in AI: "Can machines think?". The [Turing Award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_Award) is given to people that make significant contributions to Computer Science (so also AI), so I think we should remember all these people that have contributed to AI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The descriptions below are copied from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_Award) or the ACM site.

| Name | Year | Description | Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marvin Minsky | 1969 | For his central role in creating, shaping, promoting, and advancing the field of artificial intelligence | [[1]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/321574.321575) |
| John McCarthy | 1971 | McCarthy's lecture "The Present State of Research on Artificial Intelligence" is a topic that covers the area in which he has achieved considerable recognition for his work | [[2]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/33447.33448) |
| Allen Newell | 1975 | In joint scientific efforts extending over twenty years, initially in collaboration with J. C. Shaw at the RAND Corporation, and subsequently with numerous faculty and student colleagues at Carnegie Mellon University, they have made basic contributions to artificial intelligence, the psychology of human cognition, and list processing | [[3]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/360018.360022) |
| Herbert A. Simon | Idem | Idem | [[3]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/360018.360022) |
| Edward Feigenbaum | 1994 | For pioneering the design and construction of large scale artificial intelligence systems, demonstrating the practical importance and potential commercial impact of artificial intelligence technology | [[4]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/229459.233436) |
| Raj Reddy | Idem | Idem | [[4]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/229459.233436) |
| Judea Pearl | 2011 | For fundamental contributions to artificial intelligence through the development of a calculus for probabilistic and causal reasoning. | [[5]](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/pearl_2658896.cfm) |